# operation on react state

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to do mathematical operations on React states but it returns NaN in result.

```
 var b= Number(this.state.price) /  Number(this.state.BTCvalue);
 console.log(this.state.price)  //returns right price
 console.log(this.state.BTCvalue) //returns right number
 console.log(b) // returns NaN
  this.setState({
    res: b
  });
```

Comment: Can you show more code? Hard to tell from just this.  Perhaps one or both of your state objects (price, BTCvalue) isn't set.

Comment: Yes. as @mediaguru said, please share more code (probably a fiddle to get your problem).

Comment: What does -> `returns right price` actually return.. As doing -. `Number("10") / Number("2")` would return 5.

Comment: Probably, your `BTCValue` equals 0, or result of `Number(this.state.BTCvalue)` equals 0 or `NaN`

Comment: I've edited the code

Comment: Can you show what are the values of price and BTCvalue ?

Comment: @LevitatorImbalance good idea, but I believe that would return `Infinity` instead.

Comment: my BTCvalue is 3,459.2617. is it a big number to do any operation?

Comment: Well that's not a proper number in Javascript,   Try `Number('3,459.2617')`  you will see it's `NaN`, you need to parse the number into a JS number,..

Comment: @Keith oh, how could I forget! Ok, then, probably, both of values are 0, or at least one of `Number(this.state.price)` and `Number(this.state.BTCvalue)` is `NaN`, to be more correct :)

Comment: If it contains the comma in the state it will lead to a NaN

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
const { price, BTCvalue } = this.state;
const res = Number(`${price}`.replace(/,/g, '')) / Number(`${BTCvalue }`.replace(/,/g, '')); // remove "," before doing division
!isNaN(res) && this.setState({
    res
}); // check if result is number before setting state.
```

Comment: Better to explain what you are doing rather than posting code only

Comment: Thanks I solve it with some code like this. the problem was just a ",".

Answer (score 1):

Create local variable and assign value from state.

```
let {price, BTCvalue} = this.state;
```

Check if the variables are not undefined and number.
you can use 
`!undefined` and `!isNaN` to check.
Do any mathematical operation on it.

```
var res = price/BTCvalue;
```

Then set state

```
this.setState({ res: res });
```

Make sure your values are number in state.

Comment: This doesn't really answer the OP's questions, as he is doing exactly the same without the destructoring.

Comment: same result. it returns NaN for "res".

Comment: what is the value of price and BTCvalue? Share your state code.